# Disable specific dates in Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How can I disable specific days in the Bootstrap Datepicker? ([Datepicker Homepage](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/))

I am trying to provide an array of dates to the datepicker and have these specific dates (1) not be clickable and (2) have a different hover color.

My specific usage is to only allow users to select dates that have an associated data file.

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is the datepicker js code:

```
// Picker object

var Datepicker = function(element, options){
    this.element = $(element);
    this.format = DPGlobal.parseFormat(options.format||this.element.data('date-format')||'mm/dd/yyyy');
    this.picker = $(DPGlobal.template)
                        .appendTo('body')
                        .on({
                            click: $.proxy(this.click, this),
                            mousedown: $.proxy(this.mousedown, this)
                        });
    this.isInput = this.element.is('input');
    this.component = this.element.is('.date') ? this.element.find('.add-on') : false;

    if (this.isInput) {
        this.element.on({
            focus: $.proxy(this.show, this),
            blur: $.proxy(this.hide, this),
            keyup: $.proxy(this.update, this)
        });
    } else {
        if (this.component){
            this.component.on('click', $.proxy(this.show, this));
        } else {
            this.element.on('click', $.proxy(this.show, this));
        }
    }

    this.viewMode = 0;
    this.weekStart = options.weekStart||this.element.data('date-weekstart')||0;
    this.weekEnd = this.weekStart == 0 ? 6 : this.weekStart - 1;
    this.fillDow();
    this.fillMonths();
    this.update();
    this.showMode();
};

Datepicker.prototype = {
    constructor: Datepicker,

    show: function(e) {
        this.picker.show();
        this.height = this.component ? this.component.outerHeight() : this.element.outerHeight();
        this.place();
        $(window).on('resize', $.proxy(this.place, this));
        if (e ) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (!this.isInput) {
            $(document).on('mousedown', $.proxy(this.hide, this));
        }
        this.element.trigger({
            type: 'show',
            date: this.date
        });
    },

    hide: function(){
        this.picker.hide();
        $(window).off('resize', this.place);
        this.viewMode = 0;
        this.showMode();
        if (!this.isInput) {
            $(document).off('mousedown', this.hide);
        }
        this.setValue();
        this.element.trigger({
            type: 'hide',
            date: this.date
        });
    },

    setValue: function() {
        var formated = DPGlobal.formatDate(this.date, this.format);
        if (!this.isInput) {
            if (this.component){
                this.element.find('input').prop('value', formated);
            }
            this.element.data('date', formated);
        } else {
            this.element.prop('value', formated);
        }
    },

    place: function(){
        var offset = this.component ? this.component.offset() : this.element.offset();
        this.picker.css({
            top: offset.top + this.height,
            left: offset.left
        });
    },

    update: function(){
        this.date = DPGlobal.parseDate(
            this.isInput ? this.element.prop('value') : this.element.data('date'),
            this.format
        );
        this.viewDate = new Date(this.date);
        this.fill();
    },

    fillDow: function(){
        var dowCnt = this.weekStart;
        var html = '<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #aeaeae; border-top: 1px solid #aeaeae;">';
        while (dowCnt < this.weekStart + 7) {
            html += '<th class="dow">'+DPGlobal.dates.daysMin[(dowCnt++)%7]+'</th>';
        }
        html += '</tr>';
        this.picker.find('.datepicker-days thead').append(html);
    },

    fillMonths: function(){
        var html = '';
        var i = 0
        while (i < 12) {
            html += '<span class="month">'+DPGlobal.dates.monthsShort[i++]+'</span>';
        }
        this.picker.find('.datepicker-months td').append(html);
    },

    fill: function() {
        var d = new Date(this.viewDate),
            year = d.getFullYear(),
            month = d.getMonth(),
            currentDate = this.date.valueOf();
        this.picker.find('.datepicker-days th:eq(1)')
                    .text(DPGlobal.dates.months[month]+' '+year);
        var prevMonth = new Date(year, month-1, 28,0,0,0,0),
            day = DPGlobal.getDaysInMonth(prevMonth.getFullYear(), prevMonth.getMonth());
        prevMonth.setDate(day);
        prevMonth.setDate(day - (prevMonth.getDay() - this.weekStart + 7)%7);
        var nextMonth = new Date(prevMonth);
        nextMonth.setDate(nextMonth.getDate() + 42);
        nextMonth = nextMonth.valueOf();
        html = [];
        var clsName;
        while(prevMonth.valueOf() < nextMonth) {
            if (prevMonth.getDay() == this.weekStart) {
                html.push('<tr>');
            }
            clsName = '';
            if (prevMonth.getMonth() < month) {
                clsName += ' old';
            } else if (prevMonth.getMonth() > month) {
                clsName += ' new';
            }
            if (prevMonth.valueOf() == currentDate) {
                clsName += ' active';
            }
            html.push('<td class="day'+clsName+'" style="border: 0px;">'+prevMonth.getDate() + '</td>');
            if (prevMonth.getDay() == this.weekEnd) {
                html.push('</tr>');
            }
            prevMonth.setDate(prevMonth.getDate()+1);
        }
        this.picker.find('.datepicker-days tbody').empty().append(html.join(''));
        var currentYear = this.date.getFullYear();

        var months = this.picker.find('.datepicker-months')
                    .find('th:eq(1)')
                        .text(year)
                        .end()
                    .find('span').removeClass('active');
        if (currentYear == year) {
            months.eq(this.date.getMonth()).addClass('active');
        }

        html = '';
        year = parseInt(year/10, 10) * 10;
        var yearCont = this.picker.find('.datepicker-years')
                            .find('th:eq(1)')
                                .text(year + '-' + (year + 9))
                                .end()
                            .find('td');
        year -= 1;
        for (var i = -1; i < 11; i++) {
            html += '<span class="year'+(i == -1 || i == 10 ? ' old' : '')+(currentYear == year ? ' active' : '')+'">'+year+'</span>';
            year += 1;
        }
        yearCont.html(html);
    },

    click: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(e.target).closest('span, td, th');
        if (target.length == 1) {
            switch(target[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'th':
                    switch(target[0].className) {
                        case 'switch':
                            this.showMode(1);
                            break;
                        case 'prev':
                        case 'next':
                            this.viewDate['set'+DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].navFnc].call(
                                this.viewDate,
                                this.viewDate['get'+DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].navFnc].call(this.viewDate) + 
                                DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].navStep * (target[0].className == 'prev' ? -1 : 1)
                            );
                            this.fill();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'span':
                    if (target.is('.month')) {
                        var month = target.parent().find('span').index(target);
                        this.viewDate.setMonth(month);
                    } else {
                        var year = parseInt(target.text(), 10)||0;
                        this.viewDate.setFullYear(year);
                    }
                    this.showMode(-1);
                    this.fill();
                    break;
                case 'td':
                    if (target.is('.day')){
                        var day = parseInt(target.text(), 10)||1;
                        var month = this.viewDate.getMonth();
                        if (target.is('.old')) {
                            month -= 1;
                        } else if (target.is('.new')) {
                            month += 1;
                        }
                        var year = this.viewDate.getFullYear();
                        this.date = new Date(year, month, day,0,0,0,0);
                        this.viewDate = new Date(year, month, day,0,0,0,0);
                        this.fill();
                        this.setValue();
                        this.element.trigger({
                            type: 'changeDate',
                            date: this.date
                        });
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    },

    mousedown: function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    },

    showMode: function(dir) {
        if (dir) {
            this.viewMode = Math.max(0, Math.min(2, this.viewMode + dir));
        }
        this.picker.find('>div').hide().filter('.datepicker-'+DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].clsName).show();
    }
};

$.fn.datepicker = function ( option ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data('datepicker'),
            options = typeof option == 'object' && option;
        if (!data) {
            $this.data('datepicker', (data = new Datepicker(this, $.extend({}, $.fn.datepicker.defaults,options))));
        }
        if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]();
    });
};

$.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
};
$.fn.datepicker.Constructor = Datepicker;

var DPGlobal = {
    modes: [
        {
            clsName: 'days',
            navFnc: 'Month',
            navStep: 1
        },
        {
            clsName: 'months',
            navFnc: 'FullYear',
            navStep: 1
        },
        {
            clsName: 'years',
            navFnc: 'FullYear',
            navStep: 10
    }],
    dates:{
        days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
        daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
        daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
        months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    },
    isLeapYear: function (year) {
        return (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0))
    },
    getDaysInMonth: function (year, month) {
        return [31, (DPGlobal.isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month]
    },
    parseFormat: function(format){
        var separator = format.match(/[.\/-].*?/),
            parts = format.split(/\W+/);
        if (!separator || !parts || parts.length == 0){
            throw new Error("Invalid date format.");
        }
        return {separator: separator, parts: parts};
    },
    parseDate: function(date, format) {
        var parts = date.split(format.separator),
            date = new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
            val;
        if (parts.length == format.parts.length) {
            for (var i=0, cnt = format.parts.length; i < cnt; i++) {
                val = parseInt(parts[i], 10)||1;
                switch(format.parts[i]) {
                    case 'dd':
                    case 'd':
                        date.setDate(val);
                        break;
                    case 'mm':
                    case 'm':
                        date.setMonth(val - 1);
                        break;
                    case 'yy':
                        date.setFullYear(2000 + val);
                        break;
                    case 'yyyy':
                        date.setFullYear(val);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return date;
    },
    formatDate: function(date, format){
        var val = {
            d: date.getDate(),
            m: date.getMonth() + 1,
            yy: date.getFullYear().toString().substring(2),
            yyyy: date.getFullYear()
        };
        val.dd = (val.d < 10 ? '0' : '') + val.d;
        val.mm = (val.m < 10 ? '0' : '') + val.m;
        var date = [];
        for (var i=0, cnt = format.parts.length; i < cnt; i++) {
            date.push(val[format.parts[i]]);
        }
        return date.join(format.separator);
    },
    headTemplate: '<thead>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<th class="prev"><i class="icon-arrow-left"/></th>'+
                            '<th colspan="5" class="switch"></th>'+
                            '<th class="next"><i class="icon-arrow-right"/></th>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                    '</thead>',
    contTemplate: '<tbody><tr><td colspan="7" style="border: 0px;"></td></tr></tbody>'
};
DPGlobal.template = '<div class="datepicker dropdown-menu">'+
                        '<div class="datepicker-days">'+
                            '<table class=" table-condensed" style="border: 0px;">'+
                                DPGlobal.headTemplate+
                                '<tbody></tbody>'+
                            '</table>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="datepicker-months">'+
                            '<table class="table-condensed" style="border: 0px;">'+
                                DPGlobal.headTemplate+
                                DPGlobal.contTemplate+
                            '</table>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="datepicker-years">'+
                            '<table class="table-condensed" style="border: 0px;">'+
                                DPGlobal.headTemplate+
                                DPGlobal.contTemplate+
                            '</table>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
```

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: i added the datepicker js code above

Comment: not library. The code that you have implemented.

Comment: my code simply calls this library when a button is pressed. The calendar comes up correctly and I put the output into readonly text input. I haven't made any changes to the library because I can't see where to do a date check. Is there an obvious place? Let's assume my array of disabled dates is 45 values in the correct format. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234153/limit-bootstrap-datepicker-to-weekdays-only see this link. your question is similar to it.

Comment: it is similar, but different. that question refers to limiting dates by table column (i.e., there are 7 columns for the 7 days of the week). I need to limit dates by date.

Comment: I have disabled dates mean day irrespective of month just have look at [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zNbUT/112/). You might get some idea from this

Comment: Thanks, that's some help. However, I need to set conditions where the day is only disabled for certain months. Can I just use if/then statements on what you've done?

Comment: @user1569034 you can use that. But I can't find anything from which I can find date with months and year :(. If any one can help to find that we can disable them.

Comment: @jaychapani I ended up switching to this nifty php datepicker ( http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php ). I am able to send it an array of selectable dates!

Answer (score 2):

beforeShowDay should help.

Taken from the documentation:

beforeShowDay
Function(Date). Default: $.noop

A function that takes a date as a parameter and returns one of the following values:

undefined to have no effect
A Boolean, indicating whether or not this date is selectable
A String representing additional CSS classes to apply to the date’s cell
An object with the following properties:
enabled: same as the Boolean value above
classes: same as the String value above
tooltip: a tooltip to apply to this date, via the title HTML attribute

Comment: With version 1.3.1+ you can simply use `datesDisabled` option:  http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled