# how to restrict bootstrap date picker from future date

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to restrict the date picker of bootstrap from taking future date.I just want to enable the dates up to today only.How can i achieve this.

Here is my code

```
<script>
  var FromEndDate = new Date();

   $(function(){
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({
       format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
       endDate: FromEndDate, 
       autoclose: true
     });
   });
</script>
```

Can any body help regarding this

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652492/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-how-to-enable-only-specific-daterange, specifically: endDate: '+0d'

Comment: Yes,i did but it is not working...

Comment: There's also a `maxDate:0` option as stated [here](http://dotnetlearners.com/blogs/jquery-date-picker-example-to-disable-future-dates). gl

Answer (score 56):

Here is a demo of a working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/tjnicolaides/cjp7y/

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true
    });
});
</script>
```

edit: the version of Bootstrap Datepicker that supports startDate and endDate is here: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

The original project, which is the current top search result for the plugin, does not have that feature at this time: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: i tried it but it is not working in my code. date picker is working fine but it is not restricting the future dates

Comment: Are you sure all your external libraries are linked correctly? Do you see any errors in your console when you try to activate the datepicker?

Comment: Also: what version of the Datepicker library are you using?

Comment: Are you able to link to a public URL where you can demonstrate this not working?

Comment: I think you may be using a version of the plugin that doesn't support the endDate property. The project was forked and I recommend replacing your version with the latest version from here: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: yes TJ Nicolaides i found it and now it is working fine...thanks for your support... :)

Comment: i used this one http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: This answer is incomplete because it is version specific.There's a `maxDate:0` propertie that can solve some cases for different versions of the plugin. gl

Comment: I had to use `endDate: '-1d';` in order to sucessfully disable tomorrows date.  Otherwise it would still allow me to select the 8th (if today's date was the 7th).

Answer (score 28):

Set `endDate` property to `+0d`

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            endDate: '+0d',
            autoclose: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hqDb/)

Comment: it is not working in my browser. i am using google chrome to check it.

Comment: @PranavRam Don't try to use GitHub as a CDN; it doesn't work. When viewing your fiddle in Chrome, it doesn't work and I see `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` in the console.

Comment: Thanks Pranav, it works like a charm. I tried lot of other options like maxDate: '0' etc. that failed to work. But your answer saves my day.

Answer (score 7):

This code worked for me..

```js
$('#txtTo').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/MM/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    maxDate: 'now'
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

I used [date picker](https://raw.github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js) from `Git`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L9U4u/)

Comment: Try it like, 
var today = new Date();
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
   startDate: new Date(today.getFullYear()-5, today.getMonth(), today.getDate())
}); For more details see the issue
https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/485

Comment: Now the Datepicker startDate option will takes Date parameter see https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#startdate

Answer (score 6):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        endDate:'today'
    });
});
```

Adding this to your js 
user can only select date upto today's date and user cannot enter custom date value manually to the input element. If user enters a custom value then it will automatically change to the current date

Answer (score 2):

Due to issue in plugin it is getting happened use this datepicker.js

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        onRender:function(date){
            return date.valueOf() > FromEndDate.valueOf()?'disabled':'';
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Non of the above solutions work for me. After alot of searching and debugging finally I fix it. I am sharing my solution below, If someone like me facing the same problem can try the following solution.

```js
var now = new Date();
$('[name=depdate]').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    onRender: function(date) {
        if(date.valueOf() > now.addDays(15).valueOf()) {
            return 'disabled';
        } else if(date.valueOf() < now.valueOf()) {
            return 'disabled';
        }
    }
})
.on('changeDate', function(){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
}).data('datepicker');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the option endDate. All the dates after the date specified in endDate option are disabled. If you want to disable dates after today use this in your input tag:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-end-date="0d">
```

Source: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#id5

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var date=new Date();
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
    language: 'en',
    startDate : new Date('2015-01-01'),
    endDate :  date
});
```