# Bootstrap Datepicker (avoid text input or restrict manual input)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, user-input

Here is my website: http://splash.inting.org/wp/

I currently use the [Bootstrap Datepicker (range branch)](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/range) for my Call Date field and it's been great.

Although I have **2 Problems**:

1) You can manually enter strings in the input field. This is weird since the [original by eyecon](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) disallowed it by entering the current date whenever you enter non-date values. I tried the readonly attribute and it doesn't seem to work because it won't allow you to select any date.

2) I limited the date input choices to Tuesdays and Thursdays by modifying an answer in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234153/limit-bootstrap-datepicker-to-weekdays-only). Upon loading the datepicker, the default date chosen is the current date, which can be any other day of the week. I want to avoid this and have only either Tuesdays or Thursdays selected.

Comment: It would be good to mark the answer of @ogborstad as correct as it is compact and easy to grasp.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Override the key events on the input control.

```
<input onkeydown="return false" ... />
```

Comment: The best answer of all similar questions too.  If you make readonly or disabled, this prevents the new HTML input type of date from displaying the browser's built-in date picker.  This method allows the default browser experience but prohibits manual input!

Comment: Mark this as the correct answer, this answer is simply awesome. :)

Comment: mmmm... you can still double click on the text and press DEL key

Comment: Dj Mamana, just add style="pointer-events:none;" for prevent double click

Comment: yet this will kill every action when you try shortcut while focus on it

Comment: Wow, amazing answer! I was trying to first add key event that would filter out letters for date input field, but this is much better as I have popup datepicker. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use the readonly attribute and append an add-on after the input element to trigger the datepicker after the input:

```
<input type="text" name="CallDate" value="" id="CallDate" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required input-medium date date-pick" size="40" readonly>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
```

that should work.

For the second problem you could use a modified version of the datepicker from here:
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker and use the option [daysOfWeekDisabled](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker#daysofweekdisabled)

Comment: Readonly is the best way to go and it doesn't even need the "add-on" to work.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get acceptable solution as follow:

```
$(".date").datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment(),
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
}).end().on('keypress paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Hope it works for you too!

Comment: `keypress` doesn't account for delete key... I used `keydown` instead and prevented the action execution on tab (keycode = 9) and return (keycode = 13) keys.

Comment: But this disables the `delete ` and `backspace` feature as well. How can we cope with that?

Answer (score 4):

Use `onKeyDown` attribute as below. It`s working for me [To Restrict the manual input in datepicker]

```
  <input type="text" id="signedDate" name="signedDate" 
  onkeydown="event.preventDefault()" class="form-control input-med datepicker" 
  maxlength="10" placeholder="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable the keyboard events on the input element.

```
<input onkeydown="return false" ... />
```

Disable the mouse click events for input element of types like date & time.

```
<input type="date" onkeydown="return false" onclick="return false" ... />
<input type="time" onkeydown="return false" onclick="return false" ... />
```

> Like you can see, I just upgraded the top answer of this question for
> the next coming generation of developers.