# How do I set no keyboard input for Datetimepicker in default settings for Datetimepicker?

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

How do I set no keyboard input for Datetimepicker in default settings?

```js
datetimepicker : {
     icons: {
         time: "fa fa-clock-o",
         date: "fa fa-calendar",
         up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
         down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
         today: "fa fa-camera"
     },
     format : "MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm"
},
```

This is my default setting for datetime picker and I want to disable input from keyboad.

**Note: I made read only, but delete key is reponding.**

Comment: Can you return false from the onkeydown event? Like the answer in this question: [ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447057/bootstrap-datepicker-avoid-text-input-or-restrict-manual-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447057/bootstrap-datepicker-avoid-text-input-or-restrict-manual-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your component readonly and set [`ignoreReadonly`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#ignorereadonly) option to `true`, then you can use [`keyBinds`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#keybinds) option to prevent delete key to clear date selection.

As the docs says, [`keyBinds`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#keybinds) option:

> Allows for custom events to fire on keyboard press.

Live example:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
        today: "fa fa-camera"
    },
    format : "MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm",
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    keyBinds: {
        'delete': function () {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-sm-12'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" readonly/>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Socialanalyzer you're welcome, glad it helped. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you think that it solved your issue (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) how to accept an answer), you also get reputation for it!

Comment: Hey, I've been trying to fix an issue with this whole KeyBind for the past day. I want to only remove the default of the delete key press. I have tried the keyBinds: {'options': null} which does stop the component from clearing the field but it also prevents all the other default keyBind options from working. How do I only stop the delete key and not all of the other options?

Answer (score 2):

there are 2 solutions, both related to prevent the keydown event.
to do that you can use one of the following

```
<input onkeydown="return false" ... />
```

or

```
$("#yourInput").keydown(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

I hope that help you.