# meteor bootstrap3 datetimepicker disable days of week not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm using bootstrap 3 in a meteor project and would like to disable most of the days of the week in a datetime picker.

The other options I set seem to be working, but daysOfWeekDisabled won't disable any days.

I found this answer here [Limit bootstrap-datepicker to weekdays only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234153/limit-bootstrap-datepicker-to-weekdays-only) that suggests it should work (and it does in the twiddle) but I can't get my code to work.

The options I'm setting are

```
Template.requestLayout.rendered = function(){
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false,
    startDate: moment().day(12),
    defaultDate: moment().day(12),
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,1,2,3,6],
    autoclose: true
  });
}
```

Any ideas why it might not be working?

Answer (score 0):

try changing to this

```
 daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,2,3,6"
```

Comment: Exactly the same Matt. Sorry.